# Icon from Stream, Argument 'picture' must be a picture that can be used as a Icon

Tags: c#, bitmap, stream, icons

For our testing environment, I first create a bitmap.

```
private Bitmap CreateBitmap(int width, int height)
{
    return new BitMap(width, height);
}
```

Once this bitmap is created, I'm saving it to a stream.

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var bitmap = CreateBitmap(10, 10);
var icon = Icon.FromHandle(((Bitmap)bitmap).GetHicon());
icon.Save(stream);
```

Now this stream is passed to the testing framework.  However, when I try to turn the stream into  an icon:

```
var newIcon = new Icon(stream);
```

I receive an Argument Exception:

*Argument 'picture' must be a picture that can be used as a Icon.*

Any ideas why I'm getting an exception?

Comment: @Trey, I'm getting the handle in the line:
`var icon = Icon.FromHandle(...);`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what i was thinking, did you try resetting the stream position? stream.Position = 0; ?

Comment: @Trey!  I'm an idiot.  Or the error is a stupid error (Argument 'picture' must be a picture that can be used as a Icon.).

Yes, if I set the Position = 0, it works.

Comment: Awesome, have a great day.